# SonarQube configuration Issues

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, devops

I am getting a constant error while running script from Jenkins to test SonarQube installation. Please find the logs below. I have checked various posts but was not able to get a proper solution. What I have observed is when i run a bat file as administrator it runs perfectly, so that might be an issue with Jenkins not able to run that at files.

```
03:17:20  > git.exe rev-list --no-walk b14e98bc6329ee51489f7d5804bde206e7f9fb8c # timeout=10
03:17:20 No emails were`enter code here` triggered.
03:17:22 ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
03:17:22 java.io.IOException: Failed to install https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/sonar-scanner-cli/3.3.0.1492/sonar-scanner-cli-3.3.0.1492.zip to C:\Program Files\sonarqube-6.7.6\bin\windows-x86-64
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:940)
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:848)
03:17:22    at hudson.tools.DownloadFromUrlInstaller.performInstallation(DownloadFromUrlInstaller.java:77)
03:17:22    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:72)
03:17:22    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
03:17:22    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
03:17:22    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation.forNode(SonarRunnerInstallation.java:90)
03:17:22    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation.forNode(SonarRunnerInstallation.java:48)
03:17:22    at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.BuilderUtils.getBuildTool(BuilderUtils.java:56)
03:17:22    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder.perform(SonarRunnerBuilder.java:267)
03:17:22    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder.perform(SonarRunnerBuilder.java:249)
03:17:22    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
03:17:22    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
03:17:22    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:945)
03:17:22    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:683)
03:17:22    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
03:17:22    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
03:17:22    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
03:17:22    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
03:17:22    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
03:17:22 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete 'C:\Program Files\sonarqube-6.7.6\bin\windows-x86-64\InstallNTService.bat'. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.
03:17:22    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:279)
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath.deleteRecursive(FilePath.java:1305)
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath.deleteContentsRecursive(FilePath.java:1314)
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath.access$1800(FilePath.java:213)
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath$DeleteContents.invoke(FilePath.java:1289)
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath$DeleteContents.invoke(FilePath.java:1285)
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078)
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061)
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath.deleteContents(FilePath.java:1283)
03:17:22    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:904)
03:17:22    ... 19 more
03:17:22 Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Program Files\sonarqube-6.7.6\bin\windows-x86-64\InstallNTService.bat
03:17:22    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
03:17:22    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
03:17:22    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
03:17:22    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
03:17:22    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
03:17:22    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source)
03:17:22    at hudson.Util.tryOnceDeleteFile(Util.java:318)
03:17:22    at hudson.Util.deleteFile(Util.java:274)
03:17:22    ... 28 more
03:17:25 Sending e-mails to: cchopda62@gmail.com
03:17:25 ERROR: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
03:17:25 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x82sm1324127ywd.11 - gsmtp
03:17:25 
03:17:25 javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
03:17:25 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x82sm1324127ywd.11 - gsmtp
03:17:25 
03:17:25    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
03:17:25    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
03:17:25    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
03:17:25    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
03:17:25    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
03:17:25    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
03:17:25    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
03:17:25    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
03:17:25    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:131)
03:17:25    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.execute(MailSender.java:106)
03:17:25    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.cleanUp(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1094)
03:17:25    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1857)
03:17:25    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
03:17:25    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
03:17:25    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script wants to upgrade SonarScanner on the path

> C:\Program Files\sonarqube-6.7.6\bin\windows-x86-64\InstallNTService.bat

However, Jenkins doesn't have the privilege to do that. 
When Jenkins connect to Sonar installation, Jenkins user probably doesn't have enough privileges. You need to provide admin user for Jenkins on Sonar Installation instance.